# Live updating table with mySQL data

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery, mysql

I have a database that is updated with new rows almost every few seconds.

I have a table on my website that I would like to be automatically updated with the new rows added to the top without the user having to refresh the page.

I was testing the below:

```
        $(document).ready(function(){    
        loadstation();
    });
    function loadstation(){
        $("#data_download").load("/include/data_download.php");
        setTimeout(loadstation, 1000);      
    }
```

This works however I am unable to select anything in the table as when the function refreshes the request is unselects everything. I am also met with another issue of scale and after some time on the page I receive an error on the browser about memory issues "SBOX_FATAL_MEMORY_EXCEEDED".

What would be the best approach to having this be scalable and with no memory issues.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you want such a frequency of updates then investigate using websockets instead

Answer (score 1):

You could add a timestamp to your rows and only pull (and load) the extra rows happened since the last update.

Let's say you loaded the page at 00:01, then you pull and append (instead of load) the rows added since 00:01 and update the timestamp.

This would solve the issue deleting the selection, because it would add and load only the extra rows and not reload the full table on each update.

Comment: I believe the issue with selection is because it replaces DOM elements on each load

Comment: Exactly, load replace the whole element with the loaded data, that's why i suggest using append instead.

Comment: but append will leave fields with old data?

Comment: the success call can be used to take the data en append (or prepend) instead of just replacing it. It's not properly documented on the load, but instead the full info is on the $.ajax page. Still there is also a dirty solution appending an empty div and loading inside of it: `$('#maintable').append( $('<div/>').load('urlwithnewrows.php') );`

Answer (score 0):

The best approach would be use AJAX. The server should only send data of the updated fields (JSON format preferable) and javascript should simply replace `textContent` of the needed field(s).